# Dynamic cell spacing in HTML table

Tags: html, css

Okay so I don't even know if this is possible, but I'm trying to accomplish the following design with the use of a `<table>`:

[image]

I know it would be easier to just use a `<span>` and not even bother with tables, but I figured a `<table>` would actually make sense here.

This is what I have so far:

```css
table {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Population:</th>
    <td>334,300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Region:</th>
    <td>Europe</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Capital:</th>
    <td>Reykjavík</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just set a `display:flex` on `tr` and it would do the job. Like so:

```css
tr {
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Population:</th>
    <td>334,300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Region:</th>
    <td>Europe</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Capital:</th>
    <td>Reykjavík</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can reset `display` values for `th` and `td`

```css
table {
  text-align: left;
}
th,td {display:inline;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Population:</th>
    <td>334,300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Region:</th>
    <td>Europe</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Capital:</th>
    <td>Reykjavík</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```